# Cucumber cannot find StepDefinitions while running the code but manually using the option "Find Step" can find step definition

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

In the project Structure defined like below,

- src/main/java
  -- Config (RunCukesTest.java)
  -- StepDefinitions
- src/test/resources
  -- features/login[image]

When I run from `RunCukesTest.java using RunAs --> JUnit Test,` Step Definitions cannot be found by runner

When I click find Step, opens the right file. Couldn't understand where the issue is because the code was running few days back. File is downloaded from here

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4SgyzyvwKhiVTRmRDZuNXNTSjA

Runner class code

```
package helpers;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
//features= "src/test/resources/features/navigation",

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"classpath:features"},
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-report"},
        tags = {"@OnlyOneTime"},
//      dryRun = true,
        monochrome = true
        )
public class RunCukesTest{

}
```

Comment: Your project structure is not clear, it would be better if you could post a snapshot of your project folder structure.

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy Which version of `cucumber-java`, `junit`, `cucumber-junit` & `selenium-java` are you using? I am not sure if we can place `features/login` feature file within `src/test/resources`. Thanks

Comment: @kushal. added project structure

Comment: @Dev `cucumber-java: 1.2.5 
junit: 4.12
cucumber-junit: 1.2.5
selenium-java:  3.4.0`
Added the versions

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy Can you consider showing us your runner class? Thanks

Comment: @Dev `package helpers;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
//features= "src/test/resources/features/navigation",

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
  features = {"classpath:features"},
  plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-report"},
  tags = {"@OnlyOneTime"},
//  dryRun = true,
  monochrome = true
  )
public class RunCukesTest{

}`
In case if you want to download the project, available in the above link

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy You have provided a tag as `tags = {"@OnlyOneTime"},`. Can you consider showing us the implementation of the tag? Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144809/discussion-between-nagarjuna-reddy-and-dev).

Comment: glue={"stepDefinitions"} should work

Comment: @kushal. this doesn't work. if i try to run from feature file, that gives the error **Launch configuration Login.feature references non-existing project s360UIAutomation.**

Comment: hi @NagarjunaReddy :  I downloaded your project as it is from the GDrive and it works well on my machine; if I run it is a Cucumber feature, but if I provide `glue={"stepDefinitions"}` and try running it from runner then NullPointerException is thrown

Comment: Problem is coming from not able to finding hooks

Comment: @kushal.i find debugging little complicated in cucumber compared to selenium+testng. How to debug this

Comment: Moving previous comment to answer.

Comment: Is it not mandatory to provide the glue path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glue code is supposed to have path to hooks and step definitions

So modified as `glue={"helpers","stepDefinitions"}` instead of 
`glue={"helpers","classpath/stepDefinitions", "classpath/stepDefinitions.LogIn","classpath/stepDefinitions.Publish"}`

Please refer to this link [Similar issue on github](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/1127#issuecomment-303486249)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out your issue, As per your runner class, the glue path is not set.  please set glue path.`glue={"stepDefinitions"}`

```
package helpers; 
import org.junit.runner.RunWith; 
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions; 
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber; 
//features= "src/test/resources/features"@RunWith(Cucumber.class) @CucumberOptions( 
features = {"classpath:features"}, glue={"stepDefinitions"},plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-report"}, tags = {"@OnlyOneTime"}, // dryRun = true, monochrome = true ) 
public class RunCukesTest{ }
```

Comment: i did try using glue code before posting this question which was not running.

`glue = {"stepDefinitions.Login"}
Or
glue = {"stepDefinitions"}`
First one shows step definitions are not present. Second one gives null pointer exceptoin. Config is maintained in **config.properties** file

Comment: second one should work. can you give me stack trace info.

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException
       at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
       at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.sendKeys(Unknown Source)
       at stepDefinitions.LogIn.SDLogin.inputUserCredentials(SDLogin.java:29)
       at ✽.When User enter the valid credentials(features/logIn/Login.feature:5)`

Comment: Dont get this when i user `glue={"classpath:stepDefinitons", "classpath:stepDefinitons.Login","classpath:stepDefinitons.Publish"},`

Console shows the message to add steps

Answer (score 0):

Running it as a Cucumber feature, it works well, but if I provide glue={"stepDefinitions"} and try running it from runner then NullPointerException is thrown,

This problem is arising from hooks not being found. But If I move @Before and @After to the SDLogin classs, then It works well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case ,
feature files are in src/test/resources/Features/login.feature
Step definitions are in com.steps.definitions

So giving like below solved the issue.

```
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/resources/Features/login.feature"}, glue={"com.steps.definitions"},plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-report"})
public class TestRunner {
}
```

Here is the folder/package structure.
[image]