# Cucumber cannot find StepDefinitions while running from command line

Tags: java, junit, cucumber

I downloaded the latest Cucumber Java version - 4.7.2, and am ale to run the cucumber test from IDE Intellij, everything is fine in IDE. However, if run from command line then it gives me error "io.cucumber.junit.UndefinedThrowable:"

**Run test runner "RunCucumberTest" in IDE: OK**

**Cucumber-jvm Approach:**

```
java -cp "lib/cucumber-4.7.2/*" io.cucumber.core.cli.Main --glue au.com.demo.quality.stepdefinitions  --plugin pretty  --name "^demo test$" src/test/resources/features/DemoTest.feature
```

result: step undefined as above

**JUnit Approach:**

```
java -cp "../lib/cucumber-4.7.2/*;../out/production/demo" org.junit.runner.JUnitCore au.com.demo.quality.runners.RunCucumberTest
```

result: step undefined as above

**Project structure:**

```
Quality
-lib
-out
 --Production
   ---demo
   ......
-bdd
 --src
   ---test
      ----java
      ----resources
```

More details as shown in the screenshot below.

[the cucumber structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6wou.png)

I have searched in stackoverflow and google searched as well, no answer found. Useful refereces here but they are not my answer. Thanks.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/1127#issuecomment-303486249

[Cucumber cannot find StepDefinitions while running the code but manually using the option "Find Step" can find step definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44106280/cucumber-cannot-find-stepdefinitions-while-running-the-code-but-manually-using-t)

[How to run cucumber file from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30586937/how-to-run-cucumber-file-from-command-line?newreg=a8569ba04d144eaaacfc49a3de0eb47f)

https://www.toolsqa.com/cucumber/cucumber-options/

Comment: Are you including your own code on the class path?

Comment: Yes, the classpath 'lib/cucumber-4.7.2/*" is for the required jar packages, there is an old cucumber java 1.2.5 installed in the classpath "lib/", so I moved all new version to "lib/cucumber-4.7.2/*", the other one is for the class file "RunCucumberTest.class".

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. The step definition class is not able to extend another class, otherwise the step definitions wont be found.